# How to find Lie point symmetry?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been reading the Stephani's Differential equations: their solution using symmetries and I have a doubt in an excerpt.

In the chapter 4, he is exposing the procedures on how to find Lie symmetry of ODEs of different orders.

On page 29, he exposes how to find the symmetries (the functions ${\xi}$ and ${\eta}$ ) of an ODE of second order. The eq.(4.18) is a result of the making the coefficients of $(y^\prime)^{0}$ equals zero (right?).

But the eq.(4.18) has an third derivative of ${\beta}$, i.e., ${\beta}^{\prime\prime\prime}$. I don't understand why.

Comment: People here are unlike to have the book you mention at their fingertips, could you post a copy of the page you mention? You may get answers this way.

Answer (score 0):

the third derivative of $\beta(x)$ comes from the fact that $2\gamma^\prime=\beta^{\prime\prime}$. And as you can see in (4.17) $\eta$ has a term $\beta^\prime$. Hence from the term $\eta_{xx}$ in (4.13) you get the $\beta^{\prime\prime\prime}$ term.